# How to get Nokogiri to parse XML with CDATA in &lt; and &gt;

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I have an XML file with this content:

```
<DATA>
    <NAME>&lt;![CDATA[FIRSTNAME LASTNAME MIDDLENAME ]]&gt;</NAME>
    <NUM>3731</NUM>
    <person_type>4</person_type>
    <birth_date>&lt;![CDATA[01.11.1992]]&gt;</birth_date>
    <DESCRIPTION>&lt;![CDATA[DESCRIPTION]]&gt;</DESCRIPTION>
</DATA>
```

I tried to parse it with Nokogiri, but I can't get content without CDATA.

My parser script:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("test2.xml"))
root = doc.root

puts root['DATE']

doc.xpath('//DATA').each do |terr|
  puts "\nName: "+terr.xpath('NAME').text
end
```

Here's what I get:

```
Name: <![CDATA[FIRSTNAME LASTNAME MIDDLENAME ]]>
```

How do I get rid of "`![CDATA[`" in the results?

I think it's all about the entities `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of `<` and `>`, but I couldn't get Nokogiri to do anything with them.

Comment: Usually this is an XY problem, because the XML (or HTML) has been scraped from somewhere else incorrectly and entities were added. If that's what happened the correct solution is to find the original and use it. If you can't you might have to pre-process the file and force entity decoding _IF_ it will result in syntactically correct markup. If it won't you might have to extract it, then let Nokogiri parse just the section you need. I've written hundreds of scrapers and had to write some really nasty code to fix markup that'd been mangled many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input contains escaped `<` and `>` characters (`&lt;` and `&gt;`). When you use characters instead of HTML entities, everything works as expected:

```
input = "<DATA>
    <NAME><![CDATA[FIRSTNAME LASTNAME MIDDLENAME ]]></NAME>
    <NUM>3731</NUM>
    <person_type>4</person_type>
    <birth_date><![CDATA[01.11.1992]]></birth_date>
    <DESCRIPTION><![CDATA[DESCRIPTION]]></DESCRIPTION>
</DATA>"
doc = Nokogiri::XML(input)
doc.xpath('//DATA/NAME').text

=> "FIRSTNAME LASTNAME MIDDLENAME "

doc.xpath('//DATA').each do |terr|
  puts "\nName: "+terr.xpath('NAME').text
end

=> Name: FIRSTNAME LASTNAME MIDDLENAME
```

To get rid of HTML entities, you can call `CGI.unescapeHTML` on the input:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(CGI.unescapeHTML(File.read("test2.xml")))
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! This causes an error in `unescapeHTML': no implicit conversion of File into String (TypeError)

Comment: @PumPurum please check the updated answer. Instead of `File.open` use `File.read`